# Современная архитектура и подход разработки под Андроид?

Tags: android

В Андроид столько много разных архитектур разработки. Столько много способов, например работы с сетью и потоками. Я запутался.

Например:
 `WorkManager, AsyncTask, Loaders, Handler, Executors, RxJava, DownloadManager, JobScheduler` почти все же они используются для одинаковых задач ? С чем из этого в основном работают ?
Также на многих сайтах пишут, что например, фоновая работа с `AsyncTask` уже устарела, а в документации Google, есть примеры с его использованием, из-за этого начинаешь путаться.

Интструменты и паттерны архитектуры: `Architecture Components(Room, LiveData), Dagger, MVVM` - на что стоит обратить внимание, что используется в разработке?

Есть ли какой-то универсальный подход для разработки большинства приложений ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workmanager нельзя сравнивать с RxJava, AsyncTask и тд - это планировщик, его часто используют для выполнения задач, которые должны к примеру выполняться несколько раз в день, допустим сжатие файлов или отправка бэкапа на сервер.

AsyncTask сейчас никто не использует, про него стоит забыть, используйте RxJava или Kotlin coroutines.

По архитектуре я могу посоветовать MVP или MVVM.

На чем строить архитектуру, есть два варианта:
MVP - Moxy, Dagger2, RxJava
MVP или MVVM - ViewModel + LiveData, Dagger 2, Kotlin coroutines или RxJava.

Dagger 2 обязательно используется при разработке приложений.
Для работы с БД удобнее всего использовать ORM Room, для работы с сетью Retrofit.

И еще, сейчас активно используется Kotlin для разработки новых приложений, его тоже стоит иметь в арсенале знаний.